# Проверка корректности алгоритма, вычисляющего разницу между двумя датами(например длину жизни)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime db, de;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(tbegin.Text, out db) && DateTime.TryParse(tEnd.Text, out de))
    {
        if(de > db)
        {
            int years, months,days;
            years = de.Year - db.Year;
            months = de.Month - db.Month;
            days = de.Day - db.Day;

            if(months < 0)
            {
                years--;
                months += 12;
            }
            if(days < 0)
            {
                months--;
                days += DateTime.DaysInMonth(de.Year, de.Month-1);
            }
            result.Content = $"you live {years} years {months} months {days} days";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result.Content = null;
    }

}
```

- `tbegin` и `tEnd` — текстбоксы с датами
- `de` — `DateTime` представление конечной даты, `db` — `DateTime` представление начальной даты
- `result` — лейбл в который выводится результат

не уверен в правильности вычисления даты для случаев типа:

```
tbegin.Text = "20.10.1985";
tEnd.Text = "09.07.2016";
```

Comment: Интересно, а `DateTime` поддерживает вычитание или сложение? А то удобно было из одного `DateTime` вычесть другой и получить, например, длину жизни

Comment: @gil9red, поддерживает, получается TimeSpan, а с ним не слишком удобно это делать

Comment: @TuM0xA а что неудобного-то?!

Comment: @TuM0xA одна строчка вместо ваших 15 называется - "неудобно"?!

Comment: @Pavel , одна строчка никак не получиться, так как мне нужно вычислить разницу в виде "вы прожили x лет, y месяцев и z дней" а экземпляр таймспана не имеет нужных свойств

Comment: @TuM0xA а эта строчка у вас уже есть

Comment: @pavel , таймспан больше подходит для коротких промежутков, с ним не удобно работать если нужно вычислить года и месяцы.
посмотрите список его свойств

Comment: Вопрос: а если начальная дата 28 февраля, а конечная 31 марта — это один месяц? А если 1 марта по 1 апреля? А если 27 февраля по 30 марта?

Comment: @VladD ,
если следовать вышеприведенному алгоритму(в правильности которого я сильно сомневаюсь),  
28 февраля по 31 марта
 получается 31.03 - 28.02 = 03.01,
то есть 3 дня, 1 месяц .

с 1 марта по 1 апреля = 1 месяц.

с 27 февраля по 30 марта = 3 дня, один месяц

Comment: @TuM0xA: Именно поэтому я и спрашиваю. Фактически между 28.02 и 31.02 лежит ровно один месяц — март. То есть вопрос в алгоритме.

Comment: Мое личное мнение - в силу того, что понятие года может быть 365 дней, а может 366, месяца - от 28 до 31 - говорить о промежутке времени как о "столько-то лет, столько-то месяцев и столько-то дней" некорректно, потому что, получается, один и тот же промежуток может иметь разные значения...

Comment: @Harry, что же вы отвечаете на вопрос "сколько вам лет?" или "сколько месяцев вашему малышу" ?

Comment: @4per Видите ли, на вопрос, сколько мне лет, я отвечаю очень приблизительно, а не рассматривая конкретные даты :) Как и на вопрос о возрасте ребенка. Если вас устраивает этот вариант - достаточно положить год = 365.2425 дня, месяц - 30.44 дня, и не мучиться...

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете неучесть множество особенностей (високосность итп.).

Кроме того у вас нету условия `else` (`de = db` `de < db`) в `if(de > db)`

Этот вариант лучше вашего.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);
System.DateTime date3 = new System.DateTime(1996, 10, 12, 8, 42, 0);

// diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);

// date4 gets 4/9/1996 5:55:00 PM.
System.DateTime date4 = date3.Subtract(diff1);

// diff2 gets 55 days 4 hours and 20 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff2 = date2 - date3;

// date5 gets 4/9/1996 5:55:00 PM.
System.DateTime date5 = date1 - diff2;
```

Вы можете вынести вычисления в одну функцию и вызывать например `result.Content = GetDiff(две даты)`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте конвертировал DateTime в UNIX time. Unix time является обычным числом, поэтому с ним легче работать (складывать, вычитать и тд).

Конвертация DateTime в UNIX time (в примере получение текущего времени):

```
int unixTime = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
```

Конвертация UNIX time в DateTime:

```
DateTime date = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(unixTime);
```

Вы можете конвертировать необходимые даты в UNIX time, произвести необходимые расчеты, затем конвертировать результат в DateTime

Также вы можете создать свою версию UNIX time с большим числом разрядов и выбрать любую другую дату для начала отсчета, если Unix time не годится для решения вашей задачи.